Page is loading twice when using Google translator in Asp .net Webform
whene refeshing the page, page is being loading twice
I have tried this:
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en',includedLanguages: "en,es", autoDisplay: false  }, 'google_translate_element');
}

I have also tried this:
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en',
    includedLanguages: "en,es",
    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE,
    autoDisplay: false
  }, 'google_translate_element');

This one was prevented the page reloading but google translator not working
